# interchangeability of nightlights between two data(DMSP OLS) and VIRRS

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am collecting nighttime lights in African countries between 1992-2021 to utilize it as an economic growth indicator.

So far, I have managed to collect them from two data;

1992-2013 from DMSP OLS Nighttime Lights Time Series Version 4 (band: avg_vis)

2014-2021 from VIIRS Nighttime Day/Night Band Composites Version 1 (band: avg_rad)

However, I came up with the question that the indicators of nightlight evaluation differ over two data. Could you please help me to figure out how to maintain interchangeability between them? (Is there any kind of conversion coefficient???)

my code is here https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjk22001%2Ffirst_Test_NightLight%3Atest2

Answer (score 0):

There is a harmonized collection of VIIRS and DMSP OLS available for download here: https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Harmonization_of_DMSP_and_VIIRS_nighttime_light_data_from_1992-2018_at_the_global_scale/9828827

and as a GEE community dataset here: https://samapriya.github.io/awesome-gee-community-datasets/projects/hntl/